# Can git automatically rename files during clone/pull/commit?

Tags: git, rename, batch-rename

We have a collection of scripts, which have, historically, had a different name-prefix depending on whether they are used in production or a lower environment.

We're switching to git now, and would like to retain the naming convention, if possible. Suppose, I check in a script `FOO` -- can I somehow tell git to -- during clone -- rename it into **P**FOO or **D**FOO depending on some command-line argument?

Of course, I'd expect to be able to commit any subsequent changes to `DFOO` into `FOO` -- automatically...

Can git maintain different filenames between work-area and repository?

#### Why do we have such a naming difference?

These scripts exist since before the very term "devops" was coined. They are referred to by jobs executed by a similarly ancient (and mainframe-based) scheduler called "ESP". The jobs in the scheduler have different names depending on whether or not they are "production" or not -- so that operators could see immediately, from the job's very name, what level of attention to give it.

You don't need to convince me, this is, ahem, "weird" -- and I wouldn't have set it up this way myself. Not back then, not now.

But it is this way already, and I've developed a certain fondness for historical curiosities over the years -- perhaps, because I'm gradually becoming one myself...

If git has no way to maintain persistent mapping of filenames between repository and a work-area, then so be it -- we'll dispense with the practice. But, if it did, I'd use it...

Comment: This would be nice also to manage reserved words in file system of Windows like aux.c in linux kernel source code

Answer (score 0):

No, Git cannot effectively handle different filenames in the working than are in the index or the commit. Git can track renames (using [git mv](https://tecadmin.net/tutorial/git-tutorial/git-rename-files/)), but it will apply that rename as a change that branches above will replicate.

I'm going through a similar thing (transforming a process based on TFVC team projects to git in ADO).

Please Understand that git is inherently different than SVN-like version control schemes, so the answer is really no. there are things you can do to make it work the way you describe, but you are fighting the fundamental design of the system by trying to do this.

I strongly suggest you study and adopt the new technology you are embracing and its paradigm, instead of trying to contort it into what you have previously done. Believe me, I know its hard.

In particular research git workflows. [Start Here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows) to learn about some of the options. they really describe the best means to get what you need done, done without changing filenames. Start with the trunk/centralized workflow and [feature-branch workflows, expand into feature-branch-with-releases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-branching-guidance?view=azure-devops), and then look at [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), [github](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/), and [Gitlabs](https://about.gitlab.com/topics/version-control/what-is-gitlab-workflow/) workflow. the latter ones are only really required if you are maintaining multiple production releases for the long term. You really do want to be working with a specifically-selected and consistently-used workflow to be successful with Git.

Anyway to answer your question, you can write scripts around git, for whatever shell you need (we use git-bash). that said, once again, I do caution you against this approach. it will introduce an asymptote in your history, and prevent you from doing a log of a file from creation to final deletion (since it will be deleted on every promotion through your release pipeline, and a new file created).

If you use or are moving toward [CI/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CI/CD), consider that you might be able to rename files as part of your build or deployment process, if the names are only important to you after a deployment. that might satisfy your needs without introducing confusion in your version control.